# Правильность трактования предложения

Tags: грамотная-речь

В одном из пунктов декларации к договору туристической организации, заключенного со мной и моей супругой, прописано:

> Я понимаю, что недельные периоды по настоящему Договору должны быть использованы только мной и только совместно с моей (моим) супругой/ом если таковая/ой имеется
> (пропущена запятая)

Я произвел разбор предложения на:

- Основную часть:

> Я понимаю, что недельные периоды по настоящему Договору должны быть использованы только мной

- Дополнение:

> только совместно с моей (моим) супругой/ом
> (соединенных союзом "и")

- Пояснительную часть:

> если таковая/ой имеется

В итоге я трактую это предложение следующим образом:

> Любым недельным отдыхом может воспользоваться любой из членов, указанных в договоре, как отдельно, так и совместно. И невозможно участие третьего лица взамен одного из указанных в договоре.

Мне объясняют, что указанное предложение гласит об обязательном совместном использовании мною с супругой недельного периода и невозможности использования недельного периода отдельным членом договора.

Прошу Вас истолковать выше прописанное предложение.

Comment: Деклараций к договору было две (мужа и жены)?

Answer (score 0):

Буквальный смысл положения из договора таков, что обозначенные периоды должны быть использованы *только вами*, а в случае наличия у вас супруги - *только совместно с ней* (а не в одиночку и не с какой-либо другой супругой). Тот, кто вам этот смысл объясняет, *в грамматическом смысле* **прав**. Другое дело - **практика применения** этого положения: составившие его могли иметь в виду другое. Неясность и расхождение со здравым смыслом случается даже в Гражданском кодексе, и юристы порой вынуждены присоединять к буквальному смыслу ещё и здравый, чтобы избежать абсурда в практике применения отдельных пунктов статьи закона. Вот пример такой неувязки буквального смысла с реальностью (невыполнение в срок обязательств по договору отменяет сами обязательства), с комментарием юриста (ст. 429 ГК, п.6):

https://zakon.ru/blog/2015/11/17/predvaritelnyj_dogovor_kommentarij_k_novoj_redakcii_st429_gk